# A problem with the GUI in intellij error null field parent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, jpanel

I'm new and starting with intellij, I got two questions.

1- I'm making a simple app with intellij using GUI, but I have a problem, when I try to run the program, this show me the next error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hmpT.png).
I don't know why.

2- I start with netbeans but change to intellij. Is it necessary to create the program code once you have the GUI classes in the main separately, as in NetBeans, or is it not necessary? I'm attaching a screenshot to illustrate what I mean.

[image]

I have tried putting the private void createUIComponents() in the Registro class and it fails, changing some names of the JPanel.

This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Registro extends JDialog {
    private JTextField tfNombre;
    private JTextField tfEmail;
    private JPasswordField pfPassword;
    private JPasswordField pfConfirmaPassword;
    private JButton bntRegistro;
    private JButton btnCancelar;
    private JPanel registroPanel;
    
public Registro(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent);
        setTitle("Crea una nueva cuenta");
        setContentPane(registroPanel);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(450, 474));
        setModal(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Registro myForma = new Registro(null);
    }
    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the sample gui designer projects, it looks like you do not map ui components to the fields. If you can't figure it out, share your project on GitHub, see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't see a `registroPanel = new JPanel()` statement anywhere in your code, so  the "registro" variable is null". *I have tried putting the private void createUIComponents() in the Registro class and it fails,* - and you never invoke that method or have any code in that method to create the panel and add the components to the panel.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, but the text directly.